# Titan,RexterClient:Message received response timeoutConnection (8000 s) at com.tinkerpop.rexster.client.RexsterClient.execute(RexsterClient.java:185)

Tags: java, maven, titan, gremlin, rexster

I am using RexterClient to access Titan-gremlin graph in java.
But I got the beloww error on running :

```
Message received response timeoutConnection (8000 s)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.client.RexsterClient.execute(RexsterClient.java:185)
```

Below is my pom:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tinkerpop.rexster</groupId>
        <artifactId>rexster-protocol</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thinkaurelius.titan</groupId>
            <artifactId>titan-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thinkaurelius.titan</groupId>
            <artifactId>titan-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

If you guys have any idea please tell me how to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some dependency mismatches there.

- Rexster is from TinkerPop 2. You can tell because the package name starts with `com.tinkerop`.
- Titan 1.0 uses Apache TinkerPop 3.0.1. You can tell because the package name starts with `org.apache.tinkerpop`. It is not compatible with TinkerPop 2. [image]

Some pointers you should look into:

- [Gremlin Server](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#gremlin-server) is the replacement for Rexster. [Titan bundles Gremlin Server](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/server.html) within the distribution.
- You can connect to a Gremlin Server using the [Gremlin Java Driver](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#_connecting_via_java). I have an example of this at [titan-tp3-driver-example](https://github.com/pluradj/titan-tp3-driver-example).
- You should not include `titan-all` as a dependency, rather you should include the specific storage that your graph is using. For example, include `titan-cassandra` or `titan-hbase`.